# Resolution of screen text in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I have a simple kivymd App

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel

class DemoApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):        
        label = MDLabel(text = 'Hello world, this is a good example to check the quality of the output')
        return label

DemoApp().run()
```

but the resolution of the text is not very high. Is there any possibility to set the resolution/quality of graphics in Kivy? I looked in the [general config file](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.config.html), but did not find any setting.

---

I don't want to change the screen size, just the resolution.

Comment: Usually "text" does not *have* a resolution of its own, it just should use the resolution of your screen. Maybe you could add an image or two with the current and expected results?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I still have the feeling, the resolution of the text on e.g. this webpage is higher than in the Kivy frame.